# What's the purpose of giving an alias to an builtin function in Python

Tags: python

I was reading the code of Python [headq.merge](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#L369) and it seem like they're
creating alias for builtin function like `_len = len`. Just wondering what's the purpose of that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe so they can use a different function the returns a length of iterable in the future, without changing the code in more than one line?

Comment: @vaultah Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The context is that they are assigning a *global* name to a *local* name inside the function:

```
def merge(*iterables):
    ...
    _len = len
    ...
```

The expectation is that `_len` will be used many times, and accessing a local name is faster than repeatedly looking up a global name. Whether
this makes a significant difference in the overall runtime can only be
determined by benchmarking your code.

Comment: Technically, it's a builtin name. You won't find `len` in the global scope.

Comment: @chepner wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow, cheers mate.

Comment: @vaultah Looks like you're right - `dis` output shows the instruction as `LOAD_GLOBAL`. But that may or may not be a CPython implementation detail.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I suspect it's mandatory - the compiler cannot know at the compiling stage whether it'll turn out to be a builtin or a "regular" global when the code will actually be run. More in general, you can have a code object that will actually obtain the builtin or a user-defined function depending from the environment it runs in.